# Package generation failed: System.ArgumentNullException

Tags: packages

In Sitecore 10.3, When I use Package Designer to create a package, sometimes I get the following error message:

```
Package generation failed: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: source
And this is the stack trace in the logs:
Exception: System.ArgumentNullException
Message: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: source
Source: ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib
   at ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Core.StreamUtils.Copy(Stream source, Stream destination, Byte[] buffer) in /_/src/ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib/Core/StreamUtils.cs:line 130
   at Sitecore.IO.DefaultZipUtil.WriteEntry(String key, ZipOutputStream zipOutputStream, Stream inputStream)
   at Sitecore.Install.Zip.PackageWriter.Put(PackageEntry entry)
   at Sitecore.Install.Utils.EntrySorter.Flush()
   at Sitecore.Install.Framework.BaseSource`1.Populate(ISink`1 sink)
   at Sitecore.Install.PackageProject.InternalPopulate(ISink`1 sink)
   at Sitecore.Install.Framework.BaseSource`1.Populate(ISink`1 sink)
   at Sitecore.Install.Utils.EntrySorter.Populate(ISink`1 sink)
   at Sitecore.Install.PackageGenerator.GeneratePackage(PackageProject solution, ISink`1 writer)
   at Sitecore.Install.PackageGenerator.GeneratePackage(String solutionFile, String packageFile, IProcessingContext context)
   at Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Install.Dialogs.BuildPackage.AsyncHelper.Generate()
   at Sitecore.Jobs.AsyncUI.JobMonitor.TaskRunner.Run()
```

Comment: This solves the problem! https://gerhartmagdas.wordpress.com/2021/10/27/publishing-serializing-error-blobproviderexception-no-supported-provider-for-is-configured/

Answer (score 1):

I've seen an issue like that with some corrupted media items. The scenario was one of the following:

- Media item uploaded to database but then one detached media item so there was media item without a real content behind it.
- Media item created as file instead of storing media in the database and then file on the drive was deleted. So there was media item pointing to a file on the drive, but the file was not there.
- Media item created as file but one removed the File Path field content so Sitecore didn't know where to look for that item.

If your content package contains any media items, start narrowing the issue to them first.

If your content package does not contain any media items, best try to create a partial content packages to find out which part of your package is causing issues.

Answer (score 0):

I just found this article and unchecking the Blob checkbox in a single-line text.
https://gerhartmagdas.wordpress.com/2021/10/27/publishing-serializing-error-blobproviderexception-no-supported-provider-for-is-configured/
However, I could reproduce the issue with the BLOB checkbox UNchecked as well...